# java.lang.IllegalStateException : Could not find a method onClick handler with id_button

Tags: android, xml, logcat

I want to ask about my project. I create a class (RestoranView.class) which has 3 buttons: Menu, Maps and Rating. Two of them (Maps and Rating) work well but when I clicked button "Menu", it didn't work and the logcat showed those errors. I have implemented the same code. Could you help me to fix the error? Thanks in advance.

**Logcat error**

```
01-12 22:04:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 22:04:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25625): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     find a method MenuClick(View) in the activity class com.example.hellojson.RestoranView for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_menu'
01-12 22:04:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25625): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3685)
01-12 22:04:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25625): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
```

**RestoranView.java**

```
ackage com.example.hellojson;

public class RestoranView extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restoran_view);

// intent from RestoranView.class to the Map.class
public void MenuCLick (View v) {
    Intent menu = new Intent(RestoranView.this, TabMenu.class);
    menu.putExtra(Restoran.id_restoran_tags, resto.getId_restoran());
    startActivity(menu);
}

// intent from RestoranView.class to the Map.class
public void MapsClick(View v) {
    Intent maps = new Intent(RestoranView.this, Map.class);
    maps.putExtra(Restoran.nama_tags, resto.getNama());
    maps.putExtra(Restoran.latitude_tags, resto.getLatitude());
    maps.putExtra(Restoran.longitude_tags, resto.getLongitude());
    maps.putExtra(Restoran.desc_tags, resto.getDesc());
    startActivity(maps);

}

// intent from RestoranView.class to the Rating.class
public void RatingClick(View v) {
    Intent rating = new Intent(RestoranView.this, Rating.class);
    rating.putExtra(Restoran.id_restoran_tags, resto.getId_restoran());
    rating.putExtra(Restoran.nama_tags, resto.getNama());
    startActivity(rating);
    }
}
```

**RestoranView.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nama_restoran_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="Nama Restoran"
            android:textColor="@color/Navy"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_restoran_view"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="241dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alamat_restoran_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="Alamat :"
            android:textColor="@color/Navy"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_restoran_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="Phone : "
            android:textColor="@color/Navy"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deskripsi_restoran_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="Deskripsi"
            android:textColor="@color/Navy"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:onClick="MenuClick"
                android:text="Menu" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_maps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:onClick="MapsClick"
                android:text="Maps" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:onClick="RatingClick"
                android:text="Rating" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hellojson"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hellojson.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MenuUtama" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AboutMedan" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AllVenue" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TabMenu" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Map" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RestoranView" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Rating" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Search" >
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Could not find a method MenuClick(View) in the activity class com.example.hellojson.RestoranView for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_menu'
```

Change

```
 public void MenuCLick (View v)
```

to

```
 public void MenuClick (View v) { // l small
```

coz you have

```
 android:onClick="MenuClick" // its MenuClick not MenuCLick
```

And as tobor said

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.restoran_view);
} // missing }
```

Comment: Oh my God,only a L letter causes errors that I can't fix for several days. Thank you for the correction... ^_^

Comment: @user3187074 apart from that you missed `}` for `onCreate` or you missed while posting here.

Comment: I already fix the error and it works. I also already voted and checked for the accepted answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your onCreate method... add the missing } before MenuClick.

Comment: Thank you @Tobor, I already tried the suggestion and the error is I mistype the "l" letter with the big "L" letter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasnt adding the View parameter in the onClick function

changed

```
public void sendMessage()
```

to

```
public void sendMessage(View v)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on android lolly, remove the theme attribute from the xml and put the theme in android manifest. It should start working.